# Grails plugin unable to load resources that is located within itself

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a main Grails 2.3.2 project `MainGrailsApp` and I have a custom grails plug-in, `MyGrailsPlugin`, which is basically a module of the main project.
The plug-in **has its own** `.gsp`s and its own `.js` files, while also referencing `.css` files, `.gsp` templates and image **from the parent Grails project**.

Let's say there is this `PageController` inside the plug-in that renders the `view` (which is also inside the plugin) `MyGrailsPlugin/grails-app/views/page/index.gsp`. Inside that `index.gsp`, it calls for `global.css` as stylesheet and `_main.gsp` as its template, which are both found on `MainGrailsApp`, while on the other hand uses a `web-app/js/page.js` file that is located within the plug-in.

Now, when I `run-app` the main project and go to the link `localhost:8080/maingrailsapp/page`, it shows the whole page, rendered using the specified `.gsp` template, loaded fully all the `.css` files, except for the `page.js`

> `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/maingrailsapp/page.js`

Inside `index.gsp` I refer that resource using this line:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'js',file:'page.js')}" />`

Why can't it load its own `.js` file? Why can it fetch the resources that is from its parent application but unable to call its own resource? Should it, above anything else, able to locates the `page.js` file, after all that is its personal resource?

Comment: What version of Grails are you targeting and why aren't you using the asset-pipeline instead of resource?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Grails 2.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Grails resource tag has "plugin" attribute for specifying the name of the plugin where to look for the resource in. Check out [grails docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.2/ref/Tags/resource.html) for the resource tag.